# GraphicsColumn - Multiline text isn't adapting based on overall column size

Tags: graphics, text, display, column, size

I'm trying to use Graphics Column to add a label under my plots. Eventually these individual columns will be combined in a grid, and I want the height of each **plot** to be the same so I can compare data easily.
My problem is this: when the column ImageSize is such that the bottom label is multi line, it doesn't display properly. Can I tell Graphics Column to be sure to add enough room that all of the text can be seen?

Examples:
This code cuts off the label text at the bottom:

```
toPlot = {{{1, 0.024017467248908332`}, {1, 
     0.`}, {1, -0.07205240174672484`}}, {{2, 
     0.048034934497816664`}, {2, 0.09170305676855903`}, {2, 
     0.06986899563318784`}}, {{3, 0.2227074235807861`}, {3, 
     0.13537117903930138`}, {3, 0.13537117903930138`}}};
dataSetList = {"data set #1 is called a", "data set #2 is called b", 
   "data set #3 is called c"};

GraphicsColumn[{ListPlot[toPlot,
   Frame -> True,
   PlotLabel -> "This is the label for the plot"
   ],
  Style[StringJoin["Data sets included: ", 
    StringRiffle[dataSetList, ", "]], "SmallText"]},
 ImageSize -> Medium,
 Frame -> True]
```

[image: Multiline text not displaying correctly]

Same code, force the ImageSize to Large, and it works as desired:

```
toPlot = {{{1, 0.024017467248908332`}, {1, 
     0.`}, {1, -0.07205240174672484`}}, {{2, 
     0.048034934497816664`}, {2, 0.09170305676855903`}, {2, 
     0.06986899563318784`}}, {{3, 0.2227074235807861`}, {3, 
     0.13537117903930138`}, {3, 0.13537117903930138`}}};
dataSetList = {"data set #1 is called a", "data set #2 is called b", 
   "data set #3 is called c"};

GraphicsColumn[{ListPlot[toPlot,
   Frame -> True,
   PlotLabel -> "This is the label for the plot"
   ],
  Style[StringJoin["Data sets included: ", 
    StringRiffle[dataSetList, ", "]], "SmallText"]},
 ImageSize -> Large,
 Frame -> True]
```

[image: Bottom label displays correctly]

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 4):

I put your text in a `TextCell` with a limited x-direction size.

```
GraphicsColumn[{ListPlot[toPlot, Frame -> True, 
   PlotLabel -> "This is the label for the plot"], 
  TextCell[
   Style[
    StringJoin["Data sets included: ", 
     StringRiffle[dataSetList, ", "]], "SmallText"], 
   CellSize -> {300, Automatic}, TextAlignment -> Center]}, 
 ImageSize -> Automatic, Frame -> True]
```

Comment: Seems you beat me with a significantly shorter solution. Nice! You could also use `Pane[..., 300, Alignment->Center]` instead of the `TextCell`, but I'm not sure which one I prefer

Comment: I like this! It works at a wider variety of sizes, though the odd behavior of cutting of the top and bottom of the text persists as the graph gets really small. Still, this seems to do what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any method to actively control the size of individual rows/columns in `GraphicsGrid` and friends (I am already surprised that the row containing text is sized as it is). [Edit: See @Jean-Pierre's answer for a nice and simple way to get `GraphicsColumn` to deduce the correct row height]

You may be able to achieve your goals using [`ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid/):

```
toPlot = {{{1, 0.024017467248908332`}, {1, 
     0.`}, {1, -0.07205240174672484`}}, {{2, 
     0.048034934497816664`}, {2, 0.09170305676855903`}, {2, 
     0.06986899563318784`}}, {{3, 0.2227074235807861`}, {3, 
     0.13537117903930138`}, {3, 0.13537117903930138`}}};
dataSetList = {"data set #1 is called a", "data set #2 is called b", 
   "data set #3 is called c"};

    Framed@ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][
     {
      {
       ListPlot[toPlot, Frame -> True, 
        PlotLabel -> "This is the label for the plot"]
       }, {
       Graphics@Inset[
         Style[
          StringJoin["Data sets included: ", 
           StringRiffle[dataSetList, ", "]], "SmallText"],
         Automatic, Automatic, Scaled@{1, 1}
         ]
       }
      },
     ItemSize -> {1, {1, Offset[50]}},
     Spacings -> 15
     ]
```

[image]

Some notes:

- I am using [`Framed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Framed.html) for the outer frame since `PlotGrid` doesn't support this kind of frame natively.
- `PlotGrid` always expects a 2D matrix of plots, so I am giving it a column vector `{{...}, {...}}`
- `PlotGrid` expects graphics, so I wrapped the text in `Graphics[Inset[...,Automatic,Automatic,Scaled@{1,1}]]`. This produces a graphics with only your text centered in the middle, auto-wrapping lines as necessary
- The height of the row must be specified manually, which I am doing using `ItemSize -> {1, {1, Offset[50]}}`. This sets the columns to all have the same size (you only have one). The second row (via `Offset[50]`) is set to a fixed height of 50 printers points, while the first row will fill up the remaining space.
- `Spacings->15` ensures there is space for the bottom frame labels of the plot